# kafka Schema not found with schema registry

Tags: kotlin, apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry

i'm studying kafka with schema registry.

i create schema with topic `users-value` to schema registry directly.

and than i use avro plugin(davidmc24) to convert.

`servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error retrieving Avro schema{"type":"record","name":"User","namespace":"io.confluent.developer","fields":[{"name":"name","type":{"type":"string","avro.java.string":"String"},"avro.java.string":"String"},{"name":"age","type":"int"}]}] with root cause` error occured.

i don't know what is the prolem.

can anyone help me please?

below is my code.

- schema
  it is also in src/main/avro/sample.avsc

```
{
  "namespace": "io.confluent.developer",
  "type": "record",
  "name": "User",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "name",
      "type": "string",
      "avro.java.string": "String"
    },
    {
      "name": "age",
      "type": "int"
    }
  ]
}
```

- application

```
@SpringBootApplication()
class Application

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<Application>(*args)
}
```

- consumer

```
@Service
class Consumer(
    private val logger: Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Producer::class.java)
) {

    @KafkaListener(topics = ["users"], groupId = "group_id")
    @Throws(IOException::class)
    fun consume(message: ConsumerRecord<String, User>?) {
        if (message != null) {
            logger.info(String.format("#### -> Consumed message -> %s", message.value()))
        }

    }
}
```

- controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = ["/kafka"])
class KafkaController @Autowired internal constructor(private val producer: Producer) {
    @PostMapping(value = ["/publish"])
    fun sendMessageToKafkaTopic(@RequestParam("name") name: String, @RequestParam("age") age: Int) {
        producer.sendMessage(User(name, age))
    }
}
```

- producer

```
@Service
class Producer (
    private val kafkaTemplate: KafkaTemplate<String, User>? = null,
    @Value("\${topic.name}")
    private val TOPIC: String? = null
) {

    fun sendMessage(user: User) {
        this.kafkaTemplate?.send(this.TOPIC!!, user.getName(), user)
        logger.info(String.format("Produced user -> %s", user))
    }

    companion object {
        private val logger: Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Producer::class.java)
    }
}
```

- application.yml

```
server:
  port: 9000
spring:
   kafka:
     bootstrap-servers:
       - localhost:9092
     properties:
       schema.registry.url: http://localhost:8085
       auto:
         register:
           schemas: false
     consumer:
       group-id: group_id
       auto-offset-reset: earliest
       key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
       value-deserializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
     producer:
       key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
       value-serializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer

topic:
  name: users
```

- build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
        maven {
            url "https://packages.confluent.io/maven/"
        }
        maven {
            url = uri("https://jitpack.io")
        }
    }
}


plugins {
    id "com.github.davidmc24.gradle.plugin.avro" version "1.2.0"
    id "com.github.imflog.kafka-schema-registry-gradle-plugin" version "1.6.0"
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin-jpa'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-allopen'
apply plugin: "com.github.imflog.kafka-schema-registry-gradle-plugin"

group = 'com.example.exercise'
version = '0.0.1-alpha.kafka'

configurations {
    developmentOnly
    runtimeClasspath {
        extendsFrom developmentOnly
    }
}

processResources {
    def props = ['version': project.properties.get('version')]

    expand(props)
}

allOpen {
    annotation 'javax.persistence.Entity'
}

ext {
    avroVersion = "1.11.0"
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'

    implementation 'org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka:2.8.5'
    implementation "org.apache.avro:avro:${avroVersion}"
    implementation 'io.confluent:kafka-avro-serializer:7.1.1'

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

schemaRegistry {
    url = 'http://registry-url:8085/'
    quiet = true
}
```

- docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    container_name: kafka-exercise
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME=127.0.0.1
      - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT=9092
      - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
      - KAFKA_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://:29092,EXTERNAL://:9092
      - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://kafka:29092,EXTERNAL://localhost:9092
      - KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      - KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME=PLAINTEXT
      - KAFKA_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL=schemaregistry:8085

    depends_on:
      - zookeeper

  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper-exercise
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME=zookeeper

  schemaregistry:
    image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:6.2.0
    restart: always
    container_name: registry-exercise
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    environment:
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_CONNECTION_URL: "zookeeper:2181"
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: schemaregistry
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS: "http://0.0.0.0:8085"
    ports:
      - 8085:8085

  kafka-ui:
    image: provectuslabs/kafka-ui
    container_name: kafka-ui-exercise
    depends_on:
      - kafka
      - zookeeper
      - schemaregistry
    ports:
      - "8083:8080"
    restart: always
    environment:
      - KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_NAME=local
      - KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_BOOTSTRAPSERVERS=kafka:29092
      - KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_ZOOKEEPER=zookeeper:2181
      - KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_SCHEMAREGISTRY=http://schemaregistry:8085
```

this is whole code that i use.

ps. if i comment out `auto.register.schemas: false` part, it run but creating new schema.

how to make it work, without commenting out `auto.register.schemas: false`?

Comment: i can see /subjects and /schemas/ids/1 from schema registry. so i know that it registered well.

Comment: You seem to have cut off `with root cause` from the question

Answer (score 1):

i changed avro file.
the problem is avro.

```
{
    "type": "record",
    "name": "User",
    "namespace": "io.confluent.developer",
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "name",
            "type": {
                "type": "string",
                "avro.java.string": "String"
            },
            "avro.java.string": "String"
        },
        {
            "name": "age",
            "type": "int"
        }
    ]
}
```

now it works!

Comment: What difference did this make in the actual generated Java class?